# How to dynamically create/destroy modal based on div clicked (Angular2)

Tags: angular

I would like to create an application which allows you to click on any item generated and bring up a larger version. Once loaded, if you click away from the larger version onto any other part of the page it should close.

**Currently;**

If a modal is loaded and you click off it onto another thumbnail it will load another modal on top of the previous one. Clicking onto a blank space does nothing.

**What I would like to happen;**

Only one Modal should be allowed to be active at any one time, if you click away from the modal onto any other part of the page it will close it.

Here is a plunk;

http://plnkr.co/edit/Tt2FD12fGC6gIDfC3cQJ?p=preview

I'm new to Angular2 (And never used anything previously similar to it), so i'm a bit lost and would be grateful for any help!

---

Here are some code snippets;

view-list component (load data)

```
import { Component, OnInit,Output } from "@angular/core";
import { Item }   from './item.model';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-view-list',
    template: `
    <div class="container">
        <my-item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></my-item>
    </div>
    `
})
export class ViewList implements OnInit {

  items: Item[] = [
      new Item("test1", "http://www.thechromesource.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/New-Chrome-Icon-300x300.png"),
      new Item("test2", "http://www.pandasecurity.com/mediacenter/src/uploads/2010/03/safari-300x300.jpg"),
      new Item("test3", "http://cdn.toptenreviews.com/rev/prod/ce/535-firefox-box.jpg"),
      new Item("test4", "http://www.darvu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/IE-300x300.png?f1c57f")
    ]

}
```

view-grid.component (sets item into grid)

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";
import { Item }   from './item.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-item',
    template: `
       <div (click)="modalActive()" class="thumbnail">
          <img class="thumbImg" [src]="item.image" />
          <p> {{ item.name }} </p>
        </div>
        <modal *ngIf="show" [item]="item"></modal>
    `
})
export class ViewGrid {
   @Input() item: Item;


   public show: boolean = false;

    modalActive() {
            console.log(this)
            this.show = !this.show;
    }
}
```

view-modal.component (contains the modal/pop up window)

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Item }   from './item.model';


@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    template: `
     <div class="modal">
                <img class="modalImg" [src]="item.image" />
            </div>
    `
})
export class ViewModal {

     @Input() item: Item;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the one at a time modals, it sounds like you need the NgSwitch directive (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html). Another option is to store modals in an array, and display them by popping one each time the last is closed, until no more are available.

For the click to close, you'll need to apply a full-page element behind your modal with a `(click)="closeFunc()"` action.

Comment: Can I use ngIf in conjunction with ngSwitch? And if using a full-page element behind the modal, does it mean I should combine the two components so I can modify the `this.show` parameter?

Comment: NgIf and NgSwitch can be used together. The background element is required so that your modal component has something you can click to trigger the action (Otherwise you're just clicking on the main content). I'd keep the components separate and see if the Input and Output directives allow you to manage inter-component interactions in a way that satisfies your needs.